# How to replace mutiple spaces with single space in multiple txt file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've found how to replace  mutiple spaces with single space  in **one single file** but I have 40 files to do same thing (it can be more, this varies according to my analyses).

The program saves txt files with varied space between the "columns".

Ex.:

```
Position           Depth               SI
*****************************************
 655699.24         65.61    1.00
 655559.32        176.41    1.00
 655391.55        289.25    1.00
 655205.71        428.69    1.00
 655094.18        518.95    1.00
 653459.86       1611.16    1.00
 653277.26       1743.64    1.00
 653525.66       1602.15    1.00
 653596.39       1573.19    1.00
 653585.57       1591.86    1.00
 653548.80       1628.71    1.00
 653523.38       1655.96    1.00
 653494.68       1688.01    1.00
 653427.01       1729.50    1.00
 653327.08       1782.66    1.00
 653208.49       1832.50    1.00
```

I've used:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
::
:: delete first line/lines
:: and replace each occurrence of 2 or more spaces
:: by a delimiter
::
DEL output.txt   2>nul /F /Q
:: replace with ->
SET delim= 
:: set number of lines to delete 
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%i IN (L1.txt) DO (
SET line=%%i
(SET newline=)
SET count=0
CALL :change
)
GOTO :eof

:CHANGE
SET c1=%line:~0,1%
SET line=%line:~1%
IF "%c1%"==" " (SET /a count+=1) ELSE (
IF %count%==0 (SET newline=%newline%%c1%) ELSE (
IF %count%==1 (SET newline=%newline% %c1%) ELSE (
SET newline=%newline%%delim%%c1%)
SET count=0
)
)
IF DEFINED line GOTO CHANGE
::
:: You may want to preserve trailing spaces
:: or convert them...
::
IF %count%==0 GOTO print
IF %count%==1 SET newline=%newline% &GOTO print
SET newline=%newline%%delim%
:PRINT
>>output.txt ECHO %newline%
GOTO :eof$
```

With this code I replace the name of input and output files forty times, is there any automatic method of replacement the spaces that I do not need to manually replace the name of input and output files in this code?

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you doing this on, and what tools do you have available?

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Please provide a [mcve] by [edit]ing your post! Hint: take a look at the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). And of course read the [tour] to learn [ask] here...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm using Windows 7, but I do not know how to program (C, bat...)

Comment: @aschipfl I've add more information.

Comment: Thank you! Please provide sample output data relating to the shown input data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), a simple one to iterate the files and one [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to parse contents.

This is very easy as defalt delimiter is the space and consecutive delimiters are counted as only one and leading ones are ignored.
Add an `eol=*` to remove the asterisk line and save `tokens=1-3` quoted with a comma in between and you have a perfect .csv file.

**EDIT changed output delimiter to a variable and removed quotes.**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\18\SO_50910509.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Delim=,"
For %%F in (sample*.txt) do (
  ( for /f "eol=*tokens=1-3" %%A in ('type %%F') do @Echo=%%A%Delim%%%B%Delim%%%C
  ) >"%%~nF.csv"
)
```

Sample output:

```
> type sample.csv
Position,Depth,SI
655699.24,65.61,1.00
655559.32,176.41,1.00
655391.55,289.25,1.00
655205.71,428.69,1.00
...snip...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! If the output were without the quotation marks, it will be better, could you improve this? Thanks

Comment: Modilfy the `Echo="%%A","%%B,"%%C"` command to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @LotPings! It works better for me. You saved my time.

Comment: @kvratto - Please choose the check mark to the left of the answer in order to let others know this is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilise PowerShell from your batch file, to reduce each series of multiple space characters to a single one:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'C:\Users\kvratto\MyFolder' -Fi *.txt|Select -Exp FullName|%%{(GC $_) -Replace '\s+',' '|SC $_}"
```

*Just adjust `C:\Users\kvratto\MyFolder` to your holding directory containing the `.txt` files*

Comment: `powershell -NoP -C "(gci *.txt).Fullname"` is a tad shorter than the select.

Comment: It is @LotPings, this format has always been successful for me, so I've just stuck with it! _Although I suppose I should have included `-NoProfile`, so have done_

Comment: @Compo thanks for your support, your code works as well as LotPings one. Thank very much for your attention, guys. :)